# Delete Current Word in IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

How to delete a current word(word at a caret)?

Below solution forces to put caret at start or end of the word, but that is not very convenient.

```
Ctrl-BACKSPACE
Delete to word end from caret.
Ctrl-DEL
Delete to word start from caret.
```

Other solution is to select word using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> and then delete it but it is also two steps process.

Is there any shortcut or setting which can delete current word in a single step?

Comment: In case you're comfortable using the mouse, double clicking on the word has the same effect as Ctrl+W. I think this isn't really worth it, but maybe you appreciate this :)

Comment: @C-Otto Thanks for suggestion.:)  But most of the time I use keyboard and such a powerful IDE should have this feature.

Comment: Did you file a ticket? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Comment: @C-Otto. Sure will do it. Had a self-doubt because IntelliJ is so powerful that I just can't think of any missing feature like this one. :) Thanks for your time and suggestion. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IDEA macro feature is usable here:

- Open an editor and place the caret in a word
- Main menu: Edit -> Macros -> Start Macro Recording
- Press Ctrl-W, then Delete
- Main menu: Edit -> Stop Macro Recording
- A dialog pops up where you can enter a macro name like "Delete Word at Caret"
- Assign a keyboard shortcut: Main menu: File -> Settings, then Keymap -> Macros, "Delete Word at Caret"

I see you have already created a tcket in YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-180648